# CustomProvider on Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a custom **UserProvider** which works well but I cannot override function `refreshUser`.

When I refresh page I'm redirected to the **UserProvider** `__construct` function (default) then to the **CustomProvider** `__construct` function and after that to the `refreshUser` function of the default provider and not in my customProvider.

Why?

Comment: Do you have more than one UserProvider? The first one will always be used, but that can be a chain provider: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html

Comment: Yes you're right I think that ChainUserProvider of fos is called so I tried to set this line on the security.yml :
name:
    id: someId
But I have this error "__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface, string given" it's because I put this on the service.xml <argument />  but I don't know what I need to set

Comment: Please paste the relevant config in the question.